# NSPredicate to filter one-to-many relationship

Tags: swift, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

So I have two entities called Medication and Historic, where one medication can have an historical storing many dates and status (if medication was taken on time or it's late) and I have a detail view from each medication with a list of the dates that the user took that medication, like this:
[Detail view with List of dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puIb6.png)

So I'm getting this dates by converting my medication.dates into an Array of Historic and them sorting it:

```
 let medication: Medication
private var sortedHistoric: [Historic] {
    var aux = Array(medication.dates as? Set<Historic> ?? [])
    aux = aux.sorted(by: { $0.dates ?? .distantPast > $1.dates ?? .distantPast })
    return aux
}
```

This solution is working, but I don't think is the right way, so is it possible to make a FetchRequest with a predicate to get only the dates from this specific medication?
I thought of something like this:

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Historic.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Historic.dates, ascending: false)])
private var historic: FetchedResults<Historic>
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "historic.medication == @", medication)
historic.predicate = predicate
```

But its not working.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: I find it hard to understand this question, is it about filtering or sorting and how do you want to filter or sort?

Comment: It’s about both, I want to filter only the historic of this specific medication and sort it by date

Comment: Then what is wrong with your second attempt?

Comment: It’s not filtering, only sorting by date